# javascript chrome debugger equivelant PHP debugger

Tags: php, debugging

I am a frontend javascript guy, and basically am learning PHP, i have used a few PHP debugging tools, now when i code in javascript i use the chrome browser dev tools to great effect, in knowing whats going on inside a script , I.E. stuff like:

- variable watching.
- breakpoints
- step in , step out of functions .

These are really powerful, powerful features , In PHP , is there a equivalent debugger , that can compete with the chrome debugger. something that makes debugging a breeze. Not asking for a recommendation , i just want to know if there is a php debugger that has similar features(and as powerful) as the chrome debugger for javascript.

Comment: a good IDE has many debugging features

Comment: @Dagon i am trying PHPstorm !

Comment: @Dagon what IDE do you use ?

Comment: Here are the docs for using xdebug with phpstorm - https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

First, enable xdebug PHP extension on the server.

Second, an editor that can connect to xdebug. I use NetBeans, but almost all popular IDEs can do that.

Comment: what IDE do you use ?